Unexpected delay in scheduled Firebase Cloud Function execution despite minimum instance configuration
I'm well aware of cold start issues and such.
However, this Firebase cloud function is set to have 1 instance minimum, 1 max.
Additionally, it is scheduled to run once every minute.
Both conditions should exclude the cold start issue.
Additionally, this problem started appearing recently, like since a couple of months ago; it was never a problem before.
I stripped down the function to its bare minimum. Here is the full code (Node 20):
const {onSchedule} = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler");
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions/v2");


exports.StocksCandidates = onSchedule({
       schedule: "* 4-19 * * 1-5",
       minInstances: 1,
       maxInstances: 1,
       timeZone: "America/New_York"
   },
   async (context) => {
       const startTimestamp = new Date().toISOString();
       logger.debug(`Function started at ${startTimestamp}`)
   }
);

The debug shows a time of over 5 seconds past the start of each minute. It didn't use to be that way.
What could be the cause of this unwanted delay?
EDIT: I made some test and removed the minInstance... got the exact same execution delay as when I set minInstance to 1. It's as if it always cold starts even when minInstance is 1.

To check if it is actually cold starting or if the trigger request from the scheduler is slow, add the following definition to the top of your file and then call reportCallStart() from inside your Cloud Function's body. This function will only log "cold started" once and then "reused" on all subsequent calls. Let us know what it does. const reportColdStart = (() => { let starting = true; return () => { logger.debug(starting ? "Function was cold started." : "Function was reused"); starting = false; }; })();

Thank you. The function is correctly first cold started, then reused on subsequent calls. However, the processing delay is consistently a little over 5 seconds and remarkably stable, regardless of cold start or reuse. This differs from the near-instant response time previously observed on reuses.

The highest precision that Cloud Scheduler supports is one trigger event per minute per function, and which minute that trigger is fired is controlled by the schedule  option you pass in. Importantly, scheduled Cloud Functions may be retried if they return errors based on ScheduleOptions. It is a false assumption that your code will be executed exactly at 0 seconds to the hour, as the current execution may be the original scheduled request or a retry attempt.

The Cloud Scheduler will make its best effort to fire off all its requests as close to the 0 seconds to the hour mark, but there is no guarantee that it will happen exactly at 0 seconds to the hour. If you want further details, you'll need to reach out to Firebase Support as there's nothing us regular users on StackOverflow can do aside from shed some clarity on it.

Thanks. I believe the problem is the scheduler indeed, that fires at 5 seconds past minute start. Is there a way I could send my own trigger to the function in order to test function response time ?

You can manually trigger an execution from the Cloud Console or send a well formatted HTTPS request directly at the function with some rough hacks (I'm not sure if this is still possible with v2 functions, nor have I ever done it myself). You could try comparing your startTimestamp with context.scheduleTime, but I think this just returns the request's intended time rather than the actual time.

Ok thanks.... manually triggering the function still takes about 5 seconds to execute. I opened a ticket with support.

This was recognized as a bug by Firebase team, and they are working on a fix. It can  take a while for the fix to be deployed.
